# Dask-ml LabelEncoder.fit_tranform() threw AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'astype'

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, label-encoding, dask-ml

So I tried to apply LabelEncoder() function to columns that have `object` dtype on my Dask dataframe:

```
le = dm.LabelEncoder() #dm is dask-ml module
for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].dtype == type(object):
        df[column] =le.fit_transform(df[column].astype(str))
```

but it always threw the error

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Here's the full the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-f9d73f91f2c1> in <module>
      2 for column in df.columns:
      3     if df[column].dtype == type(object):
----> 4         df[column] =le.fit_transform(df[column].astype(str))
      5 
      6 

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\preprocessing\label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    131         self, y: Union[ArrayLike, SeriesType]
    132     ) -> Union[ArrayLike, SeriesType]:
--> 133         y = self._check_array(y)
    134 
    135         if isinstance(y, da.Array):

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\preprocessing\label.py in _check_array(self, y)
    109                     y = y.cat.as_known()
    110             else:
--> 111                 y = y.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
    112         return y
    113 

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in to_dask_array(self, lengths, meta)
   1429         """
   1430         if lengths is True:
-> 1431             lengths = tuple(self.map_partitions(len, enforce_metadata=False).compute())
   1432 
   1433         arr = self.values

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    277         dask.base.compute
    278         """
--> 279         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    280         return result
    281 

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    559         postcomputes.append(x.__dask_postcompute__())
    560 
--> 561     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    562     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    563 

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     82         get_id=_thread_get_id,
     83         pack_exception=pack_exception,
---> 84         **kwargs
     85     )
     86 

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    485                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    486                     else:
--> 487                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    488                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    489                 state["cache"][key] = res

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in reraise(exc, tb)
    315     if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    316         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 317     raise exc
    318 
    319 

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    220     try:
    221         task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 222         result = _execute_task(task, data)
    223         id = get_id()
    224         result = dumps((result, id))

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\optimization.py in __call__(self, *args)
    961         if not len(args) == len(self.inkeys):
    962             raise ValueError("Expected %d args, got %d" % (len(self.inkeys), len(args)))
--> 963         return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
    964 
    965     def __reduce__(self):

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in get(dsk, out, cache)
    149     for key in toposort(dsk):
    150         task = dsk[key]
--> 151         result = _execute_task(task, cache)
    152         cache[key] = result
    153     result = _execute_task(out, cache)

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py in apply(func, args, kwargs)
     29 def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
     30     if kwargs:
---> 31         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     32     else:
     33         return func(*args)

c:\users\gp62\pycharmprojects\skripsi\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\array\chunk.py in astype(x, astype_dtype, **kwargs)
    266 
    267 def astype(x, astype_dtype=None, **kwargs):
--> 268     return x.astype(astype_dtype, **kwargs)
    269 
    270 

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Any help is appreciated :)